# how to find out real data usage of C drive in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystems, disk-space

I have a wired issue as in below screen shot.

from within C drive, select everything and view from properties, total is around 40GB. however, if i view from "This PC", suppose to see 60GB free, but only 33GB free. where are the other 30GB?

any idea?

[image]

Comment: Above relates to SD card though some answers from there also answer the question; another related question see this http://superuser.com/questions/585305/size-of-the-disk-is-more-than-the-size-of-the-files-on-the-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, finally i recover my disk space by disabling "hibernate" of windows 8.1, i do not need the hibernate cache, since my OS disk is a SSD, should be faster enough for a refresh boot

Answer (score 2):

Selecting all files and showing properties skips files where don't have **access to**. Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) **([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token))** and look which folders "eat" most space.

[image]

Comment: thank you. TreeSize is a good software. notice that there is a hiberfil.sys file that eat up to 25 GB space. looking into see how can i remove it.